# /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf: no such file or directory

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I try to upgrade a node in a demo-cluster:

```
root@cluster3-worker2:~# sudo kubeadm upgrade node

couldn't create a Kubernetes client from file "/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf": failed to load admin kubeconfig: open /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf: no such file or directory
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
```

Option `--v=5` did not reveal new information.

Any clue what could be help here?

I am following this guide: [Upgrade Worker Node](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-upgrade/#upgrade-worker-nodes)

Comment: It's almost certainly because it is using some built-in [kubeadm config](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/apis/kubeadm/v1beta2#ClusterConfiguration) versus using _the_ kubeadm config that points to your actual on-disk kubelet config. Having said that, _usually_ the Node upgrade path is (1) upgrade the `kubelet` binary (2) `systemctl restart kubelet.service` (3) profit

Answer (score 1):

This was my mistake.

The node was never in the cluster before. So this was not an upgrade, but an initial join.